# How to console log out what I get back from express post request

Tags: express

I am trying to put together a POST request in Express that will send off the following data structure:

```js
{
  "policy_request_id": "onfido_applicantandsdktoken"
}
```

So I have put this together:

```js
app.post('/endpoint/in/question', (req, res) => {
   res.send({ "policy_request_id": "onfido_applicantandsdktoken" })
});
```

So in other words I am working on developing an express route to make this request out to another server that should give me back the below:

```
"data": {
  "json_data": {
     "applicant_id: "aswe4r56tyhjio"
     "sdk_token": "asdfretyuytgfghjkiuy7898uyhjkokjhygh"
   }
}
```

I would like to console log the above or whatever I get back from that request.

So I am not trying to get the following:

```
{
  "policy_request_id": "onfido_applicantandsdktoken"
}
```

I am trying to send it along via the `app.post()` request and then get back the results that come from that. Additionally I need to pass in the authorization headers.

Comment: Please update the question with your clear intent

Answer (score 1):

When you make a Post request to the express server with that endpoint `'/endpoint/in/question'` you should be able to get back the object you're sending.

You can use, [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) or any HTTP modules such as [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) or [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Using fetch it should look like this

```js
const getData = async () => {
  const data = fetch('EXPRESS_SERVER/endpoint/in/question')
     .then(res => res.json())

  // This should give you the object 
  // {"policy_request_id": "onfido_applicantandsdktoken"}
  console.log(data) 
}
```

Here's how to use [Postman](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/learn-how-to-use-postman-to-test-apis/)

Comment: my apologies if I was not clear. I want to make the request from an express server to another server, not to an express server.

Comment: Then you can use `node-fetch` or `axios` to do that following my example above because you essentially have to make HTTP calls to get data from a server

Comment: right, but I am doing it from an express server so I would be using the `app` object from `const app = express();`. Its in an express API  I am working from.

Comment: No you can't make HTTP calls with `const app = express();` If you have two different express servers and you need to get data from either one of them you need to make a request with a different HTTP client module to the API endpoint of the other server

Comment: they are not two different express servers. Only the one I built is express, the other is a third party server.

Comment: That's my point, you have to make an `HTTP` call to get data from another server but you have to use a package like the ones I've mentioned above, you can't make API calls with your express server instance `app`